# Nock how to mock put request

Tags: put, nock

My real codes like:

```
fetch(hostname+ '/api/save', {
method: "put",
credentials: "include",
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify({a: 'b'})
})
```

nock like:

```
nock(hostname)
  .put('/api/save')
  .reply(200);
```

the `hostname` includes port, but it's random port in the test. I've checked the log,  the real url and test url are same. But I don't know why it doesn't match???

Comment: Nock will match the request ONLY when the full URL is exactly same i.e. make sure the port in test is the same port being called in application. Additionally `put` requests may be using something like `form.pipe(putRequest)`, if that is the case you need to mock `form-data` or whatever other module you are using.